# How to check if a UIView is a subview of a parent view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, subview

I have an app which I add a subview to (and remove the same subview based on user interactions). I am looking for a way to check whether the subview is present or not at any given time.

For example:

In the current view (`UIView *viewA`) I add a subview (`UIView *viewB`). I then want a way of checking whether `viewB` is being displayed at any given time.

Sorry if this isn't very clear, it's quite hard to describe.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

an `UIView` stores its superview and is accessible with the [`superview`-property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/superview)  just try

```
if([viewB superview]!=nil)
    NSLog(@"visible");
else
    NSLog(@"not visible");
```

But the better approach is to use the [`hidden`-property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/hidden) of `UIView`

Answer (score 17):

I went through the same issue and consulted [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/isDescendantOfView:) and came up with this elegant solution:

```
if([self.childView isDescendantOfView:self.parentView])
{
    // The childView is contained in the parentView.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I updated to Swift4, Thanks a lot to @Shinnyx and @thomas.

```
if viewB.superview != nil{     
    print("visible")
}
else{
   print("not visible")
}
```

---

```
if selfView.isDescendant(of: self.parentView) {
    print("visible")
}
else{
    print("not visible")
}
```

> func isDescendant(of: UIView)
>
> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether the receiver is a subview of a given view or identical to that view.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method I put in the appDelegate so that I can display the entire subview hierarchy from any point.

```
// useful debugging method - send it a view and it will log all subviews
// can be called from the debugger
- (void) viewAllSubviews:(UIView *) topView Indent:(NSString *) indent  {
    for (UIView * theView in [topView subviews]){
        NSLog(@"%@%@", indent, theView);
        if ([theView subviews] != nil)
            [self viewAllSubviews:theView Indent: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",indent]];
    }
}
```

call it with a string with one character and it will indent for you.  (i.e. `[appDelegate viewAllSubviews:self.view Indent:@" "];`)

I find it useful to clear the debug pane first, then call this from the debugger, and copy it into a text editor like BBEdit that will show the indents.

You can call it using the mainWindow's view and see everything on your screen.

Comment: You can do this in the Xcode debugger with any view using `recursiveDescription` via `po [view recursiveDescription]`